# Can i pull a value from adwords and post it to a form?

Tags: php, html, google-ads-api

I have a php 'contact us' form; when submitted it directs the user to the usual 'thank you' page. On that page is where the adwords conversion tracking is located. The form also generates a new row in a simple php report for for quick viewing to see how many requests i've gotten.

Is it possible for me to tag the form with some hidden input that tells me the request came directly from my adwords campaign so i can add a 'yes or no' type column to the report?

Comment: if you enable auto tagging in adwords your destinations URLs will have ?gclid=xxx at the end. You can use a simple $_GET['gclid'] check and store the data into a cookie. The page that contains the contact form will then check to see if the cookie is there, if it finds the cookie simply echo "yes" if no echo "no" into your column